# return filename after downloading file with curl

Tags: macos, shell, curl, terminal

I would like to capture the filename to a variable of a file that is downloaded using curl. I am using the following flag to preserve the filename as in the below using `--remote-name`

My code:

```
file1=$(curl -O --remote-name 'https://url.com/download_file.tgz')
echo $file1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-w|--write-out` switch of curl:

```
file1="$(curl -O --remote-name -s \
    -w "%{filename_effective}" "https://url.com/download_file.tgz")"
echo "$file1"
```

Comment: This outputs: "curl: saved to filename 'download_file.tgz' download_file.tgz". I dont want the curl message, just the file name if possible

Comment: What is your version of curl? I tested with curl 7.76.1 and it just returns the remove filename.

Comment: im on curl 7.64.1

Comment: it works. It's because i removed the silent flag

Answer (score 1):

```
file1=download_file.tgz
url=https://url.com/$file1 #encoding this might be necessary
curl -O --remote-name $url
echo $file1
```

If, to construct the URL, you need to know the filename that you want to download, then you don't need anything from curl to identify the file that it downloaded unless there is not a 1:1 relationship between the basename of the URL and file that was downloaded.

Comment: but if my script is dynamically pulling a url, then that wouldnt work

Comment: @dataviews You should make that part of your post. It doesn't make that clear as it stands. You'll also want to indicate if the URL will result in zero, one, or more than one downloaded file.

Comment: thanks jeff, appreciate your answer anyway